# QGIS won't install on Mac OSX, during install says "The Installation Failed."

Tags: qgis, mac

I have installed the requirements:

- GDAL Complete 1.11 framework package
- Matplotlib Python module

and I've made sure these requirements are properly installed by checking library/frameworks and /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages.

When I go to install QGis I get an error message stating "The installation has failed. The installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance."

I am running El Capitan 10.11.

Comment: From what sources did you install, and which QGIS version?

Comment: I downloaded everything from http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis, including QGIS 2.10.1-1. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 2):

http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks notes that the frameworks are built for Lion, MT Lion and Mavericks.

So it seems that El Capitan 10.11 may not be supported yet.

Perhaps you should contact the maintainer, William Kyngesburye, directly about this issue.

The other download source http://qgis.dakotacarto.com/ notes that 10.11 is untested yet.

Comment: I'm on El Capitan as well, and am able to fully install QGIS Lyon 2.12-1.  However, when attempting to start the app I get the follow message window: "QGIS Cannot be opened because of a problem.  Check with the developer to make sure QGIS works with this version of OS X. You may need to reinstall the application. Be sure to install any available updates for the application and OS X."

Comment: I think that contacting William or dakotacarto is the best you can do at the moment. They may need some beta testers for the new OS.

Comment: I have the same problem as Tele-Pet "QGIS Cannot be opened because of a problem. Check with the developer to make sure QGIS works with this version of OS X. You may need to reinstall the application. Be sure to install any available updates for the application and OS X." – Tele-Pet 2 days ago", with the only difference being that the message is in Spanish (my system language). iMac 20", early 2008, 2.66GHz, 4GB memory, OS X 10.11.1. The read me file says that El Capitan is supported...

Comment: This is not exactly a solution, but I am able to run QGIS 2.12 since downgrading my OS from El Capitan back to Yosemite.

Comment: A solution would be to help the developers by contacting them directly. They may have installed something that is missing on your side.