# Grass Gis 7 does not start in OS X 10.11 El Capitan

Tags: grass-gis, osx

Recently I installed the El Capitan upgrade but unfortunately Grass 7 (from the official repository - [Grass Gis for Mac](http://grassmac.wikidot.com/downloads)) does not start any more. I also re-installed all required frameworks, but I had always the same and unique error message:

```
MacBook-Pro-di-Pankus:~ pankus$ '/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/grass.sh'; exit
Rebuilding Addon HTML manual pages index...
Rebuilding Addon menu...
Python 2.7.10 found.
Cleaning up temporary files...
Sto avviando GRASS GIS...
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libgrass_gis.7.0.1.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/gui/wxpython/gis_set.py", line 31, in <module>
    from core import globalvar
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/gui/wxpython/core/globalvar.py", line 29, in <module>
    from core.debug import Debug
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/gui/wxpython/core/debug.py", line 66, in <module>
    Debug = DebugMsg()
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/gui/wxpython/core/debug.py", line 37, in __init__
    self.SetLevel()
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/gui/wxpython/core/debug.py", line 42, in SetLevel
    self.debuglevel = int(grass.gisenv().get('WX_DEBUG', 0))
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 934, in gisenv
    s = read_command("g.gisenv", flags='n')
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 442, in read_command
    process = pipe_command(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 417, in pipe_command
    return start_command(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 355, in start_command
    if debug_level() > 0:
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 1517, in debug_level
    _debug_level = int(gisenv().get('DEBUG', 0))
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 934, in gisenv
    s = read_command("g.gisenv", flags='n')
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 445, in read_command
    return handle_errors(returncode, stdout, args, kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 312, in handle_errors
    returncode=returncode)
grass.exceptions.CalledModuleError: L'esecuzione del modulo None ['g.gisenv', '-n'] è terminata con errori
Processo terminato con codice di return diverso da zero -5. Vedi gli errori nel (error) output.
Errore nell'avvio della GUI. Se necessario, riportare l'errore agli sviluppatori di GRASS.
Avvio della modalità testuale.

Premere invio per continuare...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/grass70", line 1430, in <module>
    set_data()
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/grass70", line 675, in set_data
    gui_startup(grass_gui == 'gtext')
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/grass70", line 697, in gui_startup
    os.execlp(cmd_name, "-text")
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 329, in execlp
    execvp(file, args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 346, in execvp
    _execvpe(file, args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 382, in _execvpe
    func(fullname, *argrest)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Processo completato]
```

Apparently it misses the libintl.8.dylib library. Thus I created a link as it is described in this [page](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/R_statistics/Installation):

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libintl.8.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```

I did not solved the issues since there is a different missing library, i.e. libwx_baseu-2.8.0.dylib.
Did anyone had success in installing Grass 7 under El Capitan?

Comment: From the wiki page you mention: `As far as I can tell, they work with Mac OS X version 10.7 (AKA "Lion") through 10.10`.  Unfortunately, you are ahead of the developers :-( Probably similar to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165377/qgis-wont-install-on-mac-osx-during-install-says-the-installation-failed

Comment: If you read the first page of  [GRASS GIS on the Mac](http://grassmac.wikidot.com/): WARNING: CURRENT GRASS BINARIES MAY NOT WORK WITH EL CAPITAN - OS X 10.11. and in the Grass list: [WARNING TO MAC USERS - WAIT UPDATING TO EL CAPITAN (OS X 10.11)](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/WARNING-TO-MAC-USERS-WAIT-UPDATING-TO-EL-CAPITAN-OS-X-10-11-td5228895.html)

Comment: Many thanks for your answers. As far I can tell, however, the problem concerns only Grass (i.e. QGis works properly), thus it does not seem to be bound to frameworks. Someone who build grass from homebrew has apparently solved this issue [link](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.grass.user/52201)

Comment: I tried to install with High Sierra and got the exact same error message. Is this the same problem. Ahead of the curve?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/128190)