# Grass7 processing toolbox QGIS

Tags: qgis, installation, mac, grass-7.0

I just now edited my Grass7Utils.py file. That didn't work. I have tried changing the path in my Processing toolbox.

QGIS 2.14.3 Mac OSX 10.11.5 I did not mess with my SIP despite running Capitan. This website claimed it was fixed https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac/issues/118#issuecomment-200278686 (I got here from the website in #2 below)

What I have also done (sadly, I can't remember all of it):

1. started here- QGIS GRASS Missing Dependancy
2. compiled for macosx using homebrew (I got an error with the install --HEAD grass-71 command (no formulae found in taps). https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Compiling_on_MacOSX_using_homebrew
3. I have tried leaving the path empty in the processing window. I also set the path as: /usr/local/Cellar/grass-70/7.0.4 in my processing window.
4. I installed the app from GRASS GIS for Mac website and then set my Processing path to: /Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS.

I am pulling out my hairs at this point. Almost ready to give up and just install on a VM. I'd much rather do this on the Mac though.

Comment: You don't need to set the Processing path with GRASS GIS 7, look at  [GRASS via Processing Toolbox doesn't work in QGIS 2.8.3 on Mac?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/181431/2581) and [Bug report #14339: Mac OS X: GRASS GIS 7.0 correction](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/14339)

Comment: I have edited that file. That's one I forgot. I even tried to copy my Grass installation to the path in that guidance and still had no success.

Answer (score 1):

Before editing the file, you can control the path in the Python console

```
import processing 
import  processing.algs.grass7.Grass7Utils as ga 
ga.isMac()
True
ga.Grass7Utils.grassPath()
'/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS'
# executable 
import os 
os.path.exists(ga.Grass7Utils.grassPath() + os.sep + 'grass70.sh')
False
ga.Grass7Utils.grassPath() + os.sep + 'grass.sh'
'/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/grass.sh'
```

In the file Grass7Utils.py, this correspond to the lines

```
 else:
   folder = os.path.join(unicode(QgsApplication.prefixPath()), 'grass7')
   if not os.path.isdir(folder):
       folder = '/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS'
```

and

```
if isMac() and os.path.exists(Grass7Utils.grassPath() + os.sep + 'grass70.sh'):
       command = Grass7Utils.grassPath() + os.sep + 'grass70.sh ' \
                + Grass7Utils.grassMapsetFolder() + '/PERMANENT'
```

If you use the [M.Barton's solution (GRASS GIS for Mac)](http://grassmac.wikidot.com/downloads) simply replace grass70.sh by grass.sh

[image]

```
if isMac() and os.path.exists(Grass7Utils.grassPath() + os.sep + 'grass.sh'):
       command = Grass7Utils.grassPath() + os.sep + 'grass.sh ' \
                + Grass7Utils.grassMapsetFolder() + '/PERMANENT'
```

#### New

You should be able to launch GRASS by typing in the terminal `/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/grass.sh`

[image]

Comment: I think this is the same guidance given above as the first comment. If it's the same, I have done this and it still didn't work.

Comment: What is the result of the python script in the console ?

Comment: my python console inputs and outputs looked just like yours. The last couple lines are below. And if I look in the Grass7Utils.py file, grass.sh is what they say (as the last lines in your answer are typed).
os.path.exists(ga.Grass7Utils.grassPath() + os.sep + 'grass70.sh')
False
ga.Grass7Utils.grassPath() +os.sep + 'grass.sh'
'/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/grass.sh'     A friend told me that I have to do some front end GRASS setup (in GRASS) before I can use it in QGIS. Could that be it? @gene

Comment: Can you launch GRASS by typing in the terminal `/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/grass.sh` ?

Comment: No! @gene This is what I got: Rebuilding Addon HTML manual pages index...
Rebuilding Addon menu...
Python 2.7.10 --  64-bit  found.
arch: posix_spawnp: /Users/MyName/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/pythonw2.7: Bad CPU type in executable

Comment: What Python version did you use ? Look at the animated gif in my answer